# Stopping kafkalistenercontainerfactory if no more messages

Tags: spring-kafka

How can we stop spring Kafka consumer if no messages are left at producer?
I have created an application that read records from database and emit to Kafka for further proces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all you need to understand for yourself that there is no such a connection between producer and consumer in messaging. They really just knows nothing about each other. The producer doesn't care if there are any consumers on the other side. Any consumer doesn't care if any producers are active or not. That's really the main point of the Messaging to separate producing and consuming logic.

What may help you is called *idled container listener*. For this purpose the Framework provides for your a `ListenerContainerIdleEvent`. So, you just need to listen for this type of events and stop the container from there.

See more info in the [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#idle-containers).

Comment: Thanks Artem, will give it a try and get back in case...Just a thought, will heartbeat check let this event trigger.

Comment: Yes, they are different processes. The heartbeat is about a connection to the broken, meanwhile idle is for the period of time without messages